# Скрыть блок, если нет значения

Tags: php, javascript

```
 <div class="oldprice">Старая цена: <?php get_special_field('oldprice','',false); ?> руб.</div>
```

Старая цена подставляется из админки.Если её нет, необходимо чтобы блок div не появлялся. 
Помогите пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте прямо на сервере, заполнено ли значение переменной со старой ценой и если его нет, не выводите блок

```
<?php
$price = get_special_field('oldprice','',false);
if(!empty($price)) {
?>
  <div class="oldprice">Старая цена: <?= get_special_field('oldprice','',false) ?> руб.</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, блок не появляется, но теперь где есть старая цена, почему то указывает 1 рубль?

Comment: Исправил. У вас функция выводит цену прямо внутри, это не очень хорошо и удобно, так как приходится вычислять два раза, сделайте так, чтобы она просто возвращала значение или разбейте её на две - одна вычисляет значение, на которое можно ориентироваться, другая занимается форматированием. Если не сложно, приведите её схематическое содержание, что она возвращает? И как можно извлечь старую цену, не обращаясь к этой функции?

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь старая цена выводится правильно, только 2 раза: в div  и без него. На ваши вопросы не могу написать ответов, т.к. не понимаю ((. Вообще не понимаю в php.

Comment: Я вместо get_special_field написал return_special_field и цена стала правильно отображаться

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос содержимое функции get_special_field()

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!! Вы мне очень помогли за 5 минут, я с этим мучался 2 дня.

Comment: Вот код который у меня работает правильно  <?php
$price = return_special_field('oldprice','',false);
if(!empty($price)) {
?>
  <div class="oldprice">Старая цена: <?= return_special_field('oldprice','',false) ?> руб.</div>
<?php } ?>